# How can I override the markup of a view I printed in a template file?

Tags: 8, views, theming

I installed the [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) module on my site to render Views on the home page.

I want to make the display mode `frontpage_tasks` for the current user, his account, his stores and his groups.

```
{{ drupal_entity('user', user.id, 'frontpage_tasks') }}
{{ drupal_view('accueil_page_liste_des_taches_boutique', 'block_1') }}
{{ drupal_view('accueil_page_liste_des_taches_groupe', 'block_1') }}
```

Here is one of my Views :

[image: https://ibb.co/PFXtzXz]

The problem is that the Views module adds a lot of unnecessary markup that makes it impossible to display it correctly.

I just want to make the display mode, without any additional tags.

How to do this ? Is there a Twig code to render only Views without the additional View tags ?

[image: https://ibb.co/3CK3L9f]

**UPDATE**

I created an `views-view--accueil_page_liste_des_taches_boutique.html.twig` template. It only contains the following code :

```
{{ rows }}
```

I display the Views blocks with the code below, on my homepage :

```
                <div class="main-timeline">
                  <div class="row">
                    {{ drupal_entity('user', user.id, 'frontpage_tasks') }}
                    {{ drupal_view('accueil_page_liste_des_taches_boutique', 'block_1') }}
                    {{ drupal_view('accueil_page_liste_des_taches_groupe', 'block_1') }}
                  </div>
                </div>
```

I still have this damn markup :

```
                <div class="views-element-container">
                  <div>
                    ...
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Is there a code in TWIG to remove this basisage ?

https://ibb.co/b1tKXhQ

Comment: Views are rendered with their own twig templates. You can override them like any other template to tune the markup to your liking.

Comment: Notice that all this markup is not unnecessary if you are using views features like ajax reloading, exposed filters, pagination, facets or similar.

Comment: I rewrote the Views with the template views-view.html.twig, but there is still a completely useless div and views-element-container removed. How can I do ?

https://ibb.co/pRb9sxs

Answer (score 1):

1. You can [enable Twig debugging](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/debugging-twig-templates) for your site in sites/default/services.yml

```yaml
    parameters:
      twig.config:
        debug: true
```

2. Clear cache
3. Inspect element in the browser and you will see the path to the template
4. Copy the template to your custom theme's templates/ directory and adjust the markup

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

For override view template, you should override (views-view.html.twig) this is template for all views.

If you want override only one specific view then copy code from views-view.html.twig to:

```
[base template name]--[view machine name].html.twig
```

example: (views-view--partners--block-1.html.twig)

and override this view as you want

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should add suggestions for views using this patch https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/views-template-suggestions-2839945-2.patch recommended here https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2839945 in order to see twig suggestion in debug html, additional you should enable the twig debug as mention above